Stability of carbenes
For predicting the order of formation of carbenes from the following compounds (CHI3, CHBr3, CHF3), we can take a look at the stability of the halide anion that is formed (I- vs. Br- vs. F-) and the strength of the C-X bond that breaks, to say that a carbene would form fastest from CHI3, followed by CHBr3, and lastly CHF3.
However, a different question is rank the following carbenes formed from these compounds in their stability order:
CHI3, CHBr3, CHF3, and CHCl3. This is a question from a practice problem I was doing. My thinking here was that a more reactive starting product would form the most stable carbene, so I intially ranked CI2 as the most stable carbene, since it formed from the most reactive compound. This is similar to how the relative strengths of two acids can be determined by examining the stability of the conjugate base, where the more stable conjugate base forms the stronger acid.
However, the answer key to the question had my ordering in reverse, with CF2 as the most stable carbene, since the C-F bond is strongest. This reasoning also makes sense to me, but contradicts the above trend of a stronger reacting starting material giving the more stable product.
I was wondering how to reconcile these two ideas? I am still relatively new at organic chemistry, so am trying to understand the fundamental principles of organic reactions, so any guidance would be helpful.
Thanks

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67106/which-molecule-is-more-acidic-chf3-or-chbr3

The key thing for chemistry education is that you now recognize that the question: "rank the following carbenes formed from these compounds in their stability order: CHI3, CHBr3, CHF3, and CHCl3." is identical to the question: "rank  in their stability order: CI2, CBr2, CF2, and CCl2." A good chemistry educator writes questions to test a student's ability to distinguish different specific concepts. A less-good educator writes questions like this one that relies on semantics and reading comprehension skills to test two different concepts at the same time.
